How to use tailwindcss's @apply and others in codepen
Is it possible, and if so how, to use things like @apply and extend tailwind components in a codepen ? For example doing something like:
.button {
    @apply rounded-4 border-2 border-blue-500;
}

I tried to write my css using @apply with some css pre-processors in the pen's settings.

Does this answer your question? Tailwind + SASS not rendering styles in Codepen

I would say no, since it says it is not possible, but it is. Below is the answer I was looking for.

I don't believe CodePen has any native support for Tailwind CSS, so I'd assume you're using the CDN.
Thus, to use @apply with the CDN version, as per the documentation:

3. Try adding some custom CSS
Use type="text/tailwindcss" to add custom CSS that supports all of Tailwind's CSS features.
<style type="text/tailwindcss">
  @layer utilities {
    .content-auto {
      content-visibility: auto;
    }
  }
</style>


In the same way, you'd do:


tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      borderRadius: {
        '4': '4px',
      },
    },
  },
};
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.3"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
.button {
  @apply rounded-4 border-2 border-blue-500;
}
</style>

<div class="button">Foo</div>




As an aside, you may also wish to avoid @apply altogether as recommended by Adam Wathan, creator of Tailwind:

https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1226511611592085504

Confession: The apply feature in Tailwind basically only exists to trick people who are put off by long lists of classes into trying the framework.
You should almost never use it 
Reuse your utility-littered HTML instead.


https://twitter.com/adamwathan/status/1559250403547652097

I can say with absolute certainty that if I started Tailwind CSS over from scratch, there would be no @​apply 
The behavior is outrageously complicated, everyone struggles to build the right mental model of what it's supposed to do, and it encourages bad CSS architecture.




Thanks much! I usually don't use @apply too, this was for a special use case.
